# Understanding Power/Current/Voltage drawn by LED Strips

Tags: power-supply, current-measurement, battery-operated, led-strip, diy

I am trying to create a LED lamp which will be powered up by a battery. Lets assume I want it to run the lamp for 1hr. My LED Strips operate at 12V with 19.2W/M. I am using around 1.7 Meters(198 LEDs) of LED strips.The strip uses L2835 Type SMD LEDs.

So the LOAD here will be operating at 12V with Power of 33W and a current of 2.75A will be required.
The battery I am using is 18650 with 3.7V and 3.3A

I attempted few of the approaches to calculate the load current and volt but could not understand what was happening exactly.

### Approach 1

Connected a DC-DC step up buck converter(XL6009) with heat sink to the battery to boost the voltage to 12V
Measured the voltage/current with and w/o LOAD and the reading is as below

w/o LOAD Voltage across battery  is 3.57V
w/o LOAD buck conv o/p voltage tuned to 13.37V
there was no initial current drawn.

After connecting to the LOAD, the reading is as below
Voltage across battery reduced is 2.96V
current draw from battery to buck 1.43A
buck conv o/p voltage reduced to 9.4V
current draw from buck to load is 0.4A

### Approach 2

I thought most of the current from battery is being utilized by buck conv to boost up the voltage from 3.5 to 12V so connected three 18650 battery in series and made it as input to buck.

Measured the voltage/current with and w/o LOAD and the reading is as below
w/o LOAD Voltage across battery is 10.58V
w/o LOAD buck conv o/p voltage tuned to 12.53V
there was no initial current drawn.

After connecting to the LOAD, the reading is as below
Voltage across battery  is 10.17V
current draw from battery to buck 2.43A
buck conv o/p voltage reduced to 12.47V
current draw from buck to load is 1.12A

Even in this case, there was a slight voltage drop.
After 10mins of continuous running, the buck converter heated up and it gave a output voltage of 1.5V

### Approach 3

So the last approach I did was to connect the battery directly to my lamp and got the reading as below
w/o LOAD Voltage across battery is 10.58V, there was no initial current drawn.
After connecting to the LOAD, the reading is as below
Voltage across battery  is 10.58V
current draw from battery to load 0.7A

### Questions

- In Approach-1 -> Why did the voltage reduced? Is it because the LOAD needed more current and  not available ? But my Battery can sufficiently provide 3.3A against 2.75A which is required.
- In Approach-2 -> The XL6009 is  60V 4A Switching  Buck-Boost converter, I would like understand why it got fried, when the load is drawing 1.12A?
- In all the approaches -> As per the current calculation (I=W/V) which is will be drawn by the load (2.75A) is not been actually drawn, rather we could see lesser current been drawn at the Load? (Per multimeter readings)
- Is it the problem with battery configuration. What would be the ideal suggestion with respect to battery source if i need to run the above load for 4 hours.

Kindly help me in the regard. Let me know if any other inputs are required

Comment: 1. w/100% effeciency, 12v@1a= 3v@4a. 2. the chip is rated for up to 4a w/proper cooling, your module's cooling was insufficient. also keep in mind that for boosts, the input current is usually the limitation, not the load current. 3. a small change in load voltage on LED strips drastically reduces the load current, cutting off completely at about 9-10v. So when V sags, so does I; W is your ultimate bottleneck.

Comment: if you can live with the brightness provided, approach 3 will give you the most battery life, largely by avoiding conversion losses and the much reduced load of running the strip at 10.6v instead of 12v. Make sure the cells your'e using have protection chips with UVP to avoid damage in a driver-less setup.

Comment: A datasheet for the battery would help a great deal. Do you have access to it? Or can you provide a link to the battery you are purchasing? I want to know it's C-rating, mostly.

Answer (score 0):

Although you give clear voltage and current readings, you are ignoring the Load Regulation error and impedance of the source being transformed inefficiently to the load.  The battery ESR is the inverse of its load-regulation error and boosting a single cell's voltage by a factor of 4 increases the impedance by 4^2=16 at 12.5V which degrades load regulation by the same.  This is why Approach 3 was best by increasing the battery capacity in VA-h = Wh by a factor of 4 (cells) and ESR x4 without the expected 10~20% converter losses.

In general, it is always best to match the battery voltage range to the load and have a source impedance much lower than the load and have enough Wh capacity to exceed your requirement as using < 20h can often supply less than Ah than rating.  So compare your Watt supply to requirements conservatively and match voltage without conversions unless you understand the specs for conversion losses.